# SAS: %PUT doesn't show macro variable in the log

Tags: sas

I have the following code:

```
data name_list;
      length name $10;
      input name $;
datalines;
Peter
John
Paul
David
;
run;
proc sql ;
        select name
        into :names separated by '" "' 
        from name_list
        where substr(name,1,1) = 'P'
;
quit;
%put names;
```

The code work without any error and it does show the two names starting with P, however in the log I can't see the result of the %put statement.
After the execution of the PROC SQL I have the following log:

```
35                  quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


36         %put names;
names
```

Why the names stored into the macro variable is not printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you `%put` string that equals "names".
If you want to [`%put`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n189qvy83pmkt6n1bq2mmwtyb4oe.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) macro variable `&names`:

```
%let names=1;/*initializing macro variable*/
%put &=names;
```

> names=1;

```
%put &names;
```

> 1

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was fooled by a red line in the log due to the use of double quotes as a separator.